# VS Task Runner Explorer - Node Sass could not find a binding

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015, npm, sass, gulp

When opening the Visual Studio Task Runner Explorer, the `gulpfile.js` fails to load and this error is emitted in the Output window.

```
Failed to run "C:\DATA\Git\MyApp\MyBiz.MyApp\MyBiz.MyApp.WebsiteCore\Gulpfile.js"...
cmd.exe /c gulp --tasks-simple
C:\DATA\Git\MyApp\MyBiz.MyApp\MyBiz.MyApp.WebsiteCore\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:15
      throw new Error(errors.missingBinary());
      ^
Error: Missing binding C:\DATA\Git\MyApp\MyBiz.MyApp\MyBiz.MyApp.WebsiteCore\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-ia32-47\binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 32-bit with Node.js 5.x
Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 6.x
This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to build the binding for your current environment.
    at module.exports (C:\DATA\Git\MyApp\MyBiz.MyApp\MyBiz.MyApp.WebsiteCore\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:15:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\DATA\Git\MyApp\MyBiz.MyApp\MyBiz.MyApp.WebsiteCore\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\DATA\Git\MyApp\MyBiz.MyApp\MyBiz.MyApp.WebsiteCore\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:187:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
```

Running `gulp` runs the tasks and my SASS compiles fine.

I tried reinstalling node, I have also ensured only one `npm` runnable is in the Windows path and I've deleted the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` a few times, also tried `npm rebuild node-sass`.

All these millions of cool new front-end tools and libraries seem to be hugely broadening the surface of "things to go wrong", not very productive at all compared to previous projects.

Luke

Comment: Ashamed to say I gave up and went back to ASP.NET MVC 5 :-/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Configure VS to use the newer version of node.

Find instructions by Ryan Hayes at [Synchronize Node.JS Install Version with Visual Studio 2015](https://ryanhayes.net/synchronize-node-js-install-version-with-visual-studio-2015/)

Snippets from the instructions are below in case the link goes stale.

> I updated Node.JS outside of Visual Studio, but since VS uses its own install that is separate from any outside installation, you can potentially run into a node_modules package dependency issue where one version of npm installs a package (which makes it rely on that version of Node/npm), and then you can’t run commands in the other version (they break).  Specifically, I had an issue with node-sass and windows bindings.  The solution was to point Visual Studio to the version of Node.JS that I had already set up externally to Visual Studio.
>
> 1. First, find the Node.js installation you already have and use at the command line.

I had installed nodejs at `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\`.

> 2. Go to **Tools > Options** in Visual Studio 2015.
> 3. In this dialog, go to **Projects and Solutions > External Web Tools** to open the dialog that manages all of the 3rd party tools used within VS.  This is where Node.js is pointed to.
> 4. Add an entry at the top to the path to the node.js directory to force Visual Studio to use that version instead.
>      [image]

Comment: If anyone can vouch for this answer please comment and I'll accept.

Comment: @LukePuplett I've just run into this problem and this answer does work.

Comment: The solution for me was to make sure the PATH variable is at the top, before the other variables.

Answer (score 9):

**Tools** > **Options** > **Projects and Solutions** > **Web Package Management** > **External Web Tools** > Move **$(PATH)** above **$(VSInstalledExternalTools)**.

Comment: THIS IS THE ANSWER!

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2017 the category name is different. Instead of **External Web Tools** it is now called "Web Package management"

[Visual Studio 2017 External Tools npm Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42748833/visual-studio-2017-external-tools-npm-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with VS 2019. Below steps worked for me.

`Tools` -> `Options` -> `Projects and Solutions` -> `Web Package Management` -> `External Web Tools` -> Add the following entry `C:\Program Files\nodejs` -> and move the added to top.

[image]