# Node Sass No Binding for Your current environment

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm, node-sass

I've seen quite a few of these questions on SO, but none seem to solve or match the problem.
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Node.js 6.x.  **The odd thing is, I don't have Node.js 6.x installed.**  From the command line, node -v gives me v5.10.1.

I'm the Angular4 Universal Asp.net core visual studio 2017 template straight out of the box.

I've tried

- npm rebuild node-sass --force
- Reordering node in Web External toolsin Visual Studio

  fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
        Connection id "0HL4JSD9SSV8E": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
  System.Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Module build failed: Error: Missing binding D:\Projects\angular2\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-48\binding.node
  Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Node.js 6.x

  Found bindings for the following environments:

  - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 5.x

  This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
  Run `npm rebuild node-sass --force` to build the binding for your current environment.
      at module.exports (D:\Projects\angular2\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:15:13)
      at Object. (D:\Projects\angular2\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem on OSX. Running `npm install --save-dev node-sass` sometimes works temporarily. I haven't isolated the conditions. I'm working on this repo https://github.com/dancancro/jhipster-sample-app-ng2/tree/newmodules

Comment: I don't know if this will help you, but to fix the problem, I changed a Maven configuration in a file called pom.xml that set the node version to something different from the one given by `node -v`. Maybe there's something like that with AspNet

Comment: See my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40904101

Answer (score 3):

On **Visual Studio 2017 (15.4.1)** you should go to:

- Tools > Configure External Tools > Projects and Solutions > Web Package Management > External Web Tools

Then reorder the tools as seen below.

[image: External Web Tools]

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio ships it's own version of Node embedded so that's why you see a mismatch.
The TROUBLSHOOTING guide in the repo covers how to work around this https://github.com/sass/node-sass/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#using-node-sass-with-visual-studio-2015-task-runner

Answer (score 1):

Deleting `node_modules` folder and re-installing npm modules using `npm install` worked for me.